# Indic language not rendered in iText under certain scenarios

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

iText version – 5.3.5

I’m using an Indic language (Tamil) to generate PDF. I have made it as a phrase using base font and is written on to the document using ColumnText. Few glyphs are rendered as symbol (a question mark in between a diamond).

**com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,  Phrase(DATA, font), (float)X, (float)Y, rotationVal, RUN_DIRECTION, 0);**

Refer screenshot below.

I have used 2 sentences. When I'm using only second sentence then it is printing correct in PDF. But when I print 2 sentences together, then the second one doesn't print properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some contradictions in your question. You say that you are using iText 5.3.5, but you mention `com.lowagie.text.pdf` which was used only in version 2.1.7 and earlier.

You also expect that versions predating iText 7 support Tamil. This is not the case. If you want Tamil support, you need at least iText 7 (available as AGPL software) in combination with PdfCalligraph: http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfCalligraph

Take a look at the following screen shot to see the difference between writing Tamil *without* the addon versus Tamil *with* the addon:

[image]

PdfCalligraph is a value addon to iText 7. It is not available as open source software.